# Users with Contribute rights can't overwrite Style Library Document

Tags: access-rights

We have users who are in the standard 'members' group of a site (SP2010), and they need to occasionally upload a new version of a file in the Style Library. They have Contribute rights on the Style Library and thus on the file itself (I explicitly checked this) but the moment they try to check out the file in question, an Access Denied is thrown. Any idea why?

When a user in the owners group tries this, all goes well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2011/02/07/cannot-check-out-or-edit-documents-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) can help you. Try to play with permissions on web.

Comment: If your doclibrary has folders - check folders' permissions. If your have some customization - check permissions on those places that store additional files or layouts (such as CSS, JS, masterpage, images etc.)

Comment: Will have a look when I get back to that customer. Sounds like a good lead though, thanks.

Comment: Looked into this, but not the issue in my case. The users are members of the 'Members' group which has contribute rights across the entire site collection. There is only one break of inheritance in the chain from site collection to the file in question, and that is on the Style Library itself. The 'Members' group has contribute rights in both places.